# Prevent exceptions from extensions from pausing Chrome debugger?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Dev Tools' debugger, if Pause On Exceptions is enabled, an exception in a Chrome extension will pause the debugger. This is pretty annoying.

Is there any way to prevent these scripts pausing the debugger, while still pausing on exceptions in my app code?

Answer (score 8):

While paused at the offending exception, right-click on the extension script in Sources. Click Blackbox Script. Future exceptions from this script will be ignored by the debugger.

[image: Screenshot of Source context menu, with Blackbox Script highlighted]

Comment: Doesn't work with Tampermonkey, it throws exceptions in VM code and there's no such option in right click menu.